# On the epsilon value in tf.keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm learning ML, and I have an innocent question regarding the epsilon value used in tf.keras.

- What is exactly K.epsilon()? Is it truly the machine epsilon commonly used in other programming languages?
- If K.epsilon() is truly that concept, then why keras is not changing its value after I explicitly asked it to use double precision numbers?
- Is it enough to use K.set_floatx('float64') if I want to use double precision numbers in the whole code? Or do I need to declare that for each variable I'm using?

Please, keep in mind that I'm used to program in FORTRAN, so it is natural to me to declare the precision for each variable, and stick to over the whole code and its dependencies.

---

Consider the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

eps = K.epsilon()

print(eps)
```

The output is 1e-07, which leads me to conclude that tf.keras is using simple precision numbers (float32). Searching on the internet, I've found that we can change that using

`K.set_floatx('float64')`

Now I want to know the new value of epsilon

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

K.set_floatx('float64')

eps = K.epsilon()

print(eps)
```

but the output is again 1e-07!

That explains the questions. Please tell me if I'm misguided or something.